Не могу получить параметры запроса
Есть такой шаблон
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/auth", method="post">
        <input type="text" name="issuer" placeholder="login">
        <input type="password", name="password" placeholder="password">
        <input type="text" name="service" value={{.Service}} hidden >
        <input type="submit" value="login">
    </form>
</body>
</html>

Он лежит на сервере по пути /auth и вызывается исключительно методом GET
router.HandleFunc("/auth", controllers.MWDisplayHTML).Methods(http.MethodGet)

Ожидаемое поведение:
Ввожу логин и пароль, нажимаю "login" и происходит запрос post на сервер.
func MWDisplayHTML(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    _, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Second*4)
    defer cancel()
    templ, err := template.ParseFiles(consts.LoginHTMLPath)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }
    description, err := getDecriptionFromReq(r)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    serviceTempl := CustomTemplate{Service: description}
    err = templ.Execute(w, serviceTempl)
    if err != nil {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
        w.Write([]byte(err.Error()))
        return
    }
}

На обработчике post запросов с указанного шаблона висит обработчик, который пытается получить значение полей issuer и password. Вот функция которую я вызываю в этом обработчике для получения поля issuer
 func getIssuerNameFromRequest(r *http.Request) (string, error) {
    uname := r.URL.Query().Get(consts.IssuerKey)
    if len(uname) < consts.MinIndx {
        return consts.Empty, fmt.Errorf("%s", errs.ErrNameFieldIsEmpty)
    }
    return uname, nil
}

Но почему то, когда я ввожу логин и пароль то r.url.query.get не находит указанного поля. Раньше все работало, не могу понять что изменилось

А почему вы пытаетесь взять данные из query, если они отправлены в теле запроса?

https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Request.FormValue или https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Request.PostFormValue

@AlexeyTen странная хрень. Раньше работало и получало все из query ..

Возможно раньше форма отправлялась не POST-ом, а GET-ом. Хотя за пароль в GET нужно бить

@AlexeyTen я так понимаю, получать его соответственно, нужно через парсинг формы и функцию  r.formvalue?

FormValue/PostFormValue сами вызывают парсинг тела запроса, если надо.
Так что просто по идее достаточно просто uname := r.FormValue(consts.IssuerKey)
